# Is there a way to predict somehow the required storage for a specific blockchain?

Tags: blockchain, block-size-increase

I'd like to store a blockchain or two in my computer. Blockchains are pretty heavy (I took over 3hs to download GameCredits blockchain, and is one of the smallest blockchains, I guess). My main fear is to not be able to keep using my pc to store the blockchain (e.g. this applies for others like Litecoin).

Is there a way to track current blockchain storage sizes and predict how much space will I need the next one or two years?

Answer (score 1):

This depends on a number of factors,

1) The amount of transactions

2) How the blockchain will be compressed in the near future.

Now as i'm not quite familiar with the altcoins you stated, I can't go in depth about their compression development, but it would be fairly easy to find out what the *MAXIMUM* size of the blockchain could be.

Simply calculate every block as if it would be filled up with transactions ( maximum size), and multiply that by the amount of blocks  for/until the next year.